# Excel VBA: inject code into sub to store logs (timestamp)

Tags: vba, excel

I need to save timestamp and ID of the person who is running the sub (the sub is being ran every hour by different (3-4) people). I will get the username with:

```
*.Value = Environ("Username")
```

The main question, is how I would be able to store the logs? Indeed saving them to different spreadsheet is not an option, because people will notice that something is opening and closing. Saving in notepad is also not an option, because the file needs to be on shared drive and everyone has different letters for the drive, so we do not want to get critical error here when finding the path.

Ideally, it could save the timestamps in locked and hidden sheet in the same *.xlsm file. In column A the username and column B the timestamp (hour ; minute ; second). My question here is, do anyone have any ideas, to make it as simple as possible and what code to use, without having the code shining per 15-20 rows so even the newbies could spot it through alt+f11 and etc?

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: They may have different drive letters but the share/UNC path is the same.

Comment: If you don't want your users to read your code, then you can lock the code down so it can't be reviewed without a psasword. Probably be better to just be upfront and say "For tracking purposes the spreadsheet will put a time stamp with your username and time in the file." Show it in a visible place, in a cell which is locked from editing without a password. Note that this is not failsafe as these passwords can be trivially cracked. Perhaps save a file to the network in a folder that the students don't have access to? Perhaps have Outlook send an email to an archival account?

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I will go with very hidden sheet, so I would have everything in the same place, I will just name it temp1 or smth, because there are already like 15 sheets, so it will bare in. I need to hide it for some time (2-3 months) then I will be able to tell that there is tool for tracking purposes..

Comment: Since you can always make any sheet visible via Alt-F11. I would put this logging into a simple text file on a different UNC location. Just open text file and append the line in when the Sub is called and close the text file. Unless the code is looked at, they never know it's being logged (log is not part of the file). You may want to add encrypt/decrypt on the UNC file path to slash curiosity further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Create a sheet called 'Log' and set it to Very Hidden

```
Sheets("Log").Visible = xlVeryHidden
```

That way nobody can un-hide it. After this I suggest you lock your code so nobody can look inside the code in Tools, VBAProject Properties, Protection (From the VBE).

Of course the code would be a very simple code stored in the sub itself, something like

```
dim nextrow as long
nextrow = Sheets("Log").Cells(Sheets("Log").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) + 1
Sheets("Log").Range("A" & nextrow) = username
Sheets("Log").Range("B" & nextrow) = timestamp
```

Comment: Password protection on code is crackable, but not THAT easily (in .xlsm, compared to .xls) that a person without malicious intent would just run into it. It requires specific steps by someone who knows how.

Comment: @Tim Williams won't that lose the code, though? And prevent the person from setting the sheet to xlVisible?

Comment: xls can have macros.  Your point still stands though - password protection is sufficient to prevent *accidental* or just curious viewing.  There's little you can do about malicious use.

Comment: Actually I think I will not even lock it, so no one would spot any difference, and finally, if you have a tool that you are working with for the last few years, you are not going everyday to scan all the code to see were there any changes. I think veryhidden sheet will do. One more question, If I password lock cells from editing, will the macro put the data in it? In this way noone will be able to edit those right?

Comment: The macros bypass protection, yes. But there is no need to lock those - if it is very hidden, they can't see it anyways. If they make it visible through code, they can also unprotect the through code, so there is no point.